# How to best represent and parse tree structure of application in Android

Tags: android

I have an application which consists on a single activity. The activity contains a set of buttons, which can represent a link to a new set of buttons (let's call these buttons `SectionButton`s) or a final button (which, when clicked, will perform an action; let's call them `ActionButton`s). Both `SectionButton`s and `ActionButton`s extend a base class `AppButton`.

When the application is started, the activity shows a set of `AppButton`s. If a `SectionButton` is clicked, the activity will show the buttons corresponding to the new section, instead of the ones that it was currently displaying. This new set of buttons might contain other `SectionButton`s and `ActionButton`s.

Each section contains about six buttons, and there are a bunch of different sections. The structure of the application is therefore which buttons are showed when the application is started, which buttons are to be displayed when a `SectionButton` is clicked and what action needs to be performed when an `ActionButton` is clicked.

At the moment, I have the structure that I want documented in a TXT, like:

```
// Main section
//   |
//   +--Temperature
//   |  |
//   |  +--Too cold
//   |  |
//   |  +--Too hot
//   |
//   +--Vision & sound
//   |  |
//   |  +--Too loud
//   |  |
//   |  +--Can't hear
//   |  |
//   |  +--Can't see
//   |
//   +--Body
//      |
//      +--Pain
//      |  |
//      |  +--Head
//      |  |
//      |  +--Arms
//      |  |
//      |  +--Legs
//      |
//      +--Itch
//         |
//         +--Head
//         |
//         +--Arms
//         |
//         +--Legs
```

I then programatically create the structure by following that specification. This has the inconvenience that adding a new section or new buttons requires modifying code in a not-so straight-forward way and that the documentation and the code can get out of sync.

I want to define that structure in something like an XML, which can then be programatically parsed. That way, adding new sections or buttons to a particular section is a matter of modifying an XML, without having to delve into code, and everything is clearer.

A `SectionButton` is defined by an image (defined as an Android resource), the name of the section (defined as an Android resource) and a set of child buttons (which can be either `SectionButton`s or `ActionButton`s).

An `ActionButton` is defined by an image (defined as an Android resource), the name of the action (defined as an Android resource) and an internal string (defined as an Android resource).

What is the best way of doing it, given that I'll need to reference Android resources such as images from `res/drawable` and strings from `res/values/strings.xml`? Which tool should I use for parsing? I'd appreciate an example document representing (part of) the example structure above and some demonstration code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is declarative UI building from code.
Sounds like [Anko](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/announcing-anko-for-android/) could help you with this use case.